# Python 3 call to "list" has odd side-effects

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, side-effects

Consider the following two code snippets.

**Snippet 1**:

```
l = range(10)
list(l)
m = reversed(l)
list(m)
l = range(-1)
list(l)
list(m)
```

**Snippet 2**:

```
l = range(10)
m = reversed(l)
l = range(-1)
list(l)
list(m)
```

The only difference between them is that Snippet 2 does not call `list(l)` and `list(m)` in its first half.

Bizzarely, the final call to `list(m)` in Snippet 1 returns

```
[]
```

whereas the final call to `list(m)` in Snippet 2 returns

```
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

These are different values!

This is not the behavior I would have expected. Presumably, the earlier calls to `list(l)` and `list(m)` in Snippet 1 are triggering some kind of memory optimization; is anybody able to explain to me precisely what is going on, please?

```
>>> l = range(10)
>>> list(l)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> m = reversed(l)
>>> list(m)
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
>>> l = range(-1)
>>> list(l)
[]
>>> list(m)
[]
>>>
>>> l = range(10)
>>> m = reversed(l)
>>> l = range(-1)
>>> list(l)
[]
>>> list(m)
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Iterators, like the return value of `reversed`, are single-use. If you want to iterate over them twice, you need to get two iterators.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thank  you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reversed` returns an iterator which is single-use: it is exhausted after you feed it to `list` (which builds a list from the reversed items) the first time.

In consequent runs, it will yield the empty list since `m`, the iterator supplied, is exhausted and can't yield any more values:

```
m = reversed(l)
print(m) # <list_reverseiterator at 0x7fd2b8518fd0>
list(m)  # [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
list(m)  # []  (exhausted)
```

In your second snippet, you haven't called `list` on `m` as you do in the first, thereby not exhausting it.

You're only calling it once, in the end, and getting the list you see.

Comment: Nitpick: a one trick pony can only do one thing, not only do it once. Better to call it single-use.